# Restore desktop frames for Emacs server

Tags: frames, daemon, desktop

The version of `desktop.el` that comes with Emacs 24.4 allows restoring frames as well as windows and buffers. This works fine for an Emacs server (i.e., daemon) with at least one open frame. However, a newly started started Emacs server that attempts to load a desktop file while starting reports restoring frames, but no frames appear. When I open a new frame via `emacsclient`, the buffers have been restored, so the desktop file is being read correctly.

Is there a flag for restoring desktop frames for an Emacs server which is just starting (i.e., has no open frames)?

Comment: If you don't find that this is already supported (e.g. if no good ready-made answer is suggested here), consider reporting this as an enhancement request: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Definitely will do that. I would be surprised if the Emacs devs overlooked this.

Comment: Is this emacs in a terminal session, or with the GUI?